# path parameter of require() in node.js

Tags: node.js, syntax

I am learning node.js

for example, I try

```
var server = require("./myserver.js");
```

and

```
var server = require("./myserver");
```

why do both work? What is this kind of things call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at node's source code for the [`require`-function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0347574834ab1a0714c2c97bf6bb07592556abd8/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L970), you can see that `require`'s `load`-function [calls a function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0347574834ab1a0714c2c97bf6bb07592556abd8/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L949) `findLongestRegisteredExtension` to determine the file-extension. [This function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0347574834ab1a0714c2c97bf6bb07592556abd8/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L394) returns `.js` as its default value if no extension could be determined:

```
function findLongestRegisteredExtension(filename) {
  const name = path.basename(filename);
  let currentExtension;
  let index;
  let startIndex = 0;
  while ((index = name.indexOf('.', startIndex)) !== -1) {
    startIndex = index + 1;
    if (index === 0) continue; // Skip dotfiles like .gitignore
    currentExtension = name.slice(index);
    if (Module._extensions[currentExtension]) return currentExtension;
  }
  return '.js';
}
```

That's why using both `require("./myserver.js");`  or `require("./myserver");` will resolve the same module.

Comment: Thx, And I want to ask what if I have other file with the same name? e.g myserver.json etc,  will it always search .js at first ?

Comment: Afaik it will only load the json file if you explicitly add the `.json` extension to the `require`-call. So if you leave the extension, it always loads the `.js` file, I think.